# Bootstrap navbar-text alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

When i want to add a navbar-text it push up the text and also the navbar-item. How can i make it align with the items to the left? Since if i delete the text, everything seems fine, but i would like to have the text there.

```
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <p class="navbar-text">Välkommen {{ user.get_full_name }}</p>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'site:logout' %}"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logga ut </a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'site:login' %}"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Logga in </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only `navbar-text` on the `li`...

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="navbar-text">
        user.get_full_name
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'site:logout' %}"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logga ut </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/rHJhDbPuOP

An alternate option is to remove the `margin-bottom` (`mb-0`) from the `<p>`...

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <p class="navbar-text mb-0">full_name</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, i had no idea i could place text on the bar without define it as an item :)